# What statistical model have such $\theta = \sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} x_i}{2n}}$ estimation for parameter?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

What statistical model have such estimation for parameter? Model have only one parameter.

$$\theta = \sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} x_i}{2n}}$$

I've tried to build model from exponetial family. But it seems that this model should be not from exponetial family.

Could you guess statistical model?

Comment: How about $f(x;\theta) = \frac{2}{\theta^2}\exp\left(-\frac{2x}{\theta^2}\right)$?